# Conv2d function in keras and understanding of going to lower layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have following code. It has five convolition layers with 128 (3X3) filters then decreasing by 2 as 64(3X3), 32(3X3), 16(3X3) and 8(3X3). I want to understand the output of first layer, second layer, how I can visualise it and also please guide me when we go to next layer we can see that output of first layer is much more than input of second layer, so how we manage it?

And also at the last line, when we concatenate, it saves in which order (is it 8X8 output)? please help me rgarding this matter as I am new in pyhton.
Code is as follows.

```
ds = 2

t1 = Input((None, None, 1)) (t1 is grey scale image of 35X35)
conv1a = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(t1)
conv2a = Conv2D(128 // ds, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1a)
conv3a = Conv2D(128 // (ds * 2), (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2a)
conv4a = Conv2D(128 // (ds ** 3), (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3a)
conv5a = Conv2D(128 // (ds ** 4), (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4a)

fl = Input((None, None, 1)) (fl i also a grey scale image of size 35X35)
conv1b = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(fl)
conv2b = Conv2D(128 // ds, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1b)
conv3b = Conv2D(128 // (ds * 2), (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2b)
conv4b = Conv2D(128 // (ds ** 3), (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3b)
conv5b = Conv2D(128 // (ds ** 4), (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4b)

concat = concatenate([conv5a, conv5b], axis=-1)
```

Comment: for visualization use tensorboard.

Comment: Use `model.summary()` or use tensorboard. Also check [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-deep-learning-neural-network-model-keras/).

Comment: thanks for your answer. any idea about the output of first layer and how it is downgraded to lesser filters?